# What is the equation analogous to the Schrödinger equation in classical mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, time-evolution

I have a question that asks me for an equation in classical mechanics which would be analogous to the quantum mechanical Schrödinger equation.

Comment: The paraxial wave equation is formally equivalent to the Schrödinger equation.

Comment: As I said earlier also, maybe the Classical Wave Equation? But without the imaginary coefficient, it resembles more or less the diffusion equation.

Comment: Schrödinger equation is analogous to Newton's equation in classical mechanics. Both corresponds to the basic dynamical equations of motion in their respective regime. You can derive the Schrödinger equation from the classical Hamiltonian of a free particle by substituting the corresponding operators in quantum mechanics in the place of the classical  quantities.

Answer (score 2):

The analogue of the Schrödinger equation in classical mechanics is the Hamilton-Jacobi equation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation): you can find a lot of links explaining this analogy or look at the original articles by Schrödinger.

Comment: see also the third bullet point of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Broglie%E2%80%93Bohm_theory#Derivations

Answer (score 0):

The Hamiltonian is essentially just "energy" in the classical sense - if you replace momentum in the classical energy equation with the hermitian momentum operator (used in QM for the momentum observable) then you will get the 'Hamiltonian' for the energy observable in the QM sense. Based on deeper mathematical theory, involving Hilbert spaces etc, you can essentially set up an eigenvalue problem, and this will yield the so-called Schrodinger's equation, yielding an energy eigenvalue and a corresponding energy eigenstate for each quantum number. (Assuming you meant time-indep!)

Hope this helps.